# TCP server in WebExtension

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

Is there a way to start the TCP server that will listen port using Firefox WebExtension? I know that exist way to start server with XUL/XPCOM extension, but it is obsolete and will not be supported (deprecated) from November 2017.
The same question interests and about google chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, a Chrome Extension / Firefox WebExtension cannot open a socket to listen.

However, you could have a separate [Native Host](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Native_messaging) component that does it for you. It will need to be installed separately.

Comment: Can I run JS code from WebExtension in tab page context?

Comment: Sounds like a separate question, but you're looking either for content scripts or [injected scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/insert-code-into-the-page-context-using-a-content-script).

Comment: Yes, another question. I want that Native Host component give JS commands to WebExtension and WebExtenstion execute it from page context. Your example on a link executes JS code once.

Comment: I'm afraid you'll need to read up on [extension architecture](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Anatomy_of_a_WebExtension) first.

Comment: I just ran my eyes through this article 15 minutes before I wrote this topic :-)
I correctly understood you that you wanted to say that the answer to my question is under the #Web_content. Should i use *runtime.sendMessage()* and *runtime.onMessage* to implement what i want?

Comment: Now I just want to understand whether it is possible to realize what I want.
If possible, I will later read the details of WebExtension and try to understand what I need to do

Answer (score 1):

### Not *yet*.

> With the removal of XPCOM, add-ons access to UDP and TCP sockets will disappear, which will cause problems for a number of add-ons.
> – [Adam Roach](https://wiki.mozilla.org/User:AdamRoach)

This is being tracked at Firefox bug [FF#1435798 (libdweb)](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=libdweb):

- `Open`
- `Type: enhancement`
- The actual [TCP](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=libdweb-tcp) and [UDP](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=libdweb-udp) components are each `Priority: P3 (Backlog)`

> It's been discussed and everyone seems to like the idea.

> if somebody is motivated to work on this, sketching out a design that meets the requirements outlined above would be the first step.

> we are all for a well thought out API and that's the next step for someone to take on.

You can keep an eye on their progress for it, or lend a hand, at the [Git repo](https://github.com/mozilla/libdweb).

---

Of course, as the other answerer notes, a native host / buddy software component is the *only* workaround at this time; you've *got* to run some kind of privileged/native code to open sockets until or unless `libdweb` gets released.